# How to work with pandas list that stores a 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, multidimensional-array

I have two lists. One that stores some 45 symbols. And the other stores a 2d array associated with each symbols. I have trouble working with the latter. The latter has (45 items), each associated with a DataFrame with shape (1259, 7) i.e. it has 1259 row and 7 columns. Now what sort of operations can I perform on this list with shape? Mainly I want to print the 2D array of a specific symbol and store it in another dataframe. Here is some sample code.

```
#Load Tickers from our predefined universes, 1.1, 2.1,3.1
#Get a list of OHLCV dataframes to pass into logrets above
tickers_univ1p1=get_universe_tickers('1.1', exchange='us_equity')[0]
ohlcv_data1p1=get_ohlcv_from_db_raw(tickers_univ1p1,datetime.now()-relativedelta(years=5), datetime.now())
```

**tickers_univ1p1** is a list of 45 tickers. **ohlcv_data1p1** as you can guess stores the Open, High, Low, Close, Volume data of these 45 tickers. **print(ohlcv_data1p1)** returns data for 45 tickers as shown below:

[                          Date    Open      High       Low   Close    Volume  
0    2017-05-12 00:00:00-04:00   65.27   66.1900   65.2100   66.06   6093684
1    2017-05-15 00:00:00-04:00   66.07   66.8500   65.9500   66.67   8528259
2    2017-05-16 00:00:00-04:00   66.73   66.9200   66.3300   66.85   6313511
3    2017-05-17 00:00:00-04:00   64.98   66.3400   64.6100   65.37  12771573
4    2017-05-18 00:00:00-04:00   65.37   66.1000   65.2000   65.63   6001088
...                        ...     ...       ...       ...     ...       ...
1254 2022-05-05 00:00:00-04:00  152.77  153.3200  150.0400  152.18   6869281
1255 2022-05-06 00:00:00-04:00  149.68  153.5200  149.0150  152.83   6145590
1256 2022-05-09 00:00:00-04:00  151.62  153.5362  148.9338  150.96   6968994
1257 2022-05-10 00:00:00-04:00  151.27  154.5300  150.5100  152.09   6525184
1258 2022-05-11 00:00:00-04:00  151.02  154.7600  150.9400  151.96   5424957

```
      Vwap
```

0      65.9868
1      66.5633
2      66.6778
3      65.4776
4      65.6352
...        ...
1254  151.9179
1255  151.9679
1256  151.6744
1257  152.4678
1258  152.7975

[1259 rows x 7 columns]

Showing only 1 item above. Another 44 items like this gets printed.

Comment: Please share some example input data, along with an example desired output if possible, as text.

Comment: @BeRT2me I added some sample code. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Can you paste that as text, rather than an image?

Comment: @BeRT2me done. please check and let me know.